# How do you load a dynamic template into $uibModal.open( ) ( Angular UI bootstrap)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using angular ui bootstrap. I want to define a generic Modal Window to provide some default buttons, like close, ok, title etc.

The user's modal body template is provided as a template url. How can I merge the user's modal body template into my generic modal window template?

Below is my generic Modal Window template, 
modal-window.tpl.html

```
<div class="modal-header"><h3>{{ ctrl.headerText }}</h3></div>

<div class="modal-body">


    <<<< The user's template provided as URL should be embedded in here >>>


</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn" data-ng-click="ctrl.close()"> {{ctrl.closeButtonText}} </button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary"   data-ng-click="ctrl.ok();"> {{ctrl.actionButtonText}}</button>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `ng-include` for that.
If you put the users template url on the scope in your controller:
`userTemplate='users/template.html'` . Then you could do something like:

```
...
<div class="modal-body">
    <div ng-include="ctrl.userTemplate"></div>
</div>
...
```

If you also need a custom controller you can define one like this:

**users/template.html**:

```
<div ng-controller="CustomModalController as modalCtrl">
    {{modalCtrl.foo}}
</div>
```

The only drawback is that this controller needs to be defined in the parent controller. In this case the controller were `userTemplate='users/template.html'` is defined.

Comment: nice solution,
but what about a custom controller?

Comment: Edited my answer for this case

Comment: This was perfect for my use case! Thanks